# Multiple docker containers (domains) with NGINX as proxy

Tags: apache, nginx, docker, proxy, virtualization

I have one server, one IP, and multiple websites.

What I try to do is to isolate all websites, each website in it's own docker container.

What I need, its the NGINX as proxy, and one Docker container for each website.

I tried something like that (as root on server):

/etc/hosts :

```
127.0.0.1       example.com
```

NGINX config:

```
http {
    upstream app-a {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    }

    server {
            listen 80;
            server_name example.com www.example.com;

            location / {
                proxy_pass         http://app-a;
                proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

            }
    }
}
```

Docker:

```
docker run -d -p 3000:80 coreos/apache /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
```

`curl example.com` :

*`<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>`*

Why do I get the NGINX response and not the Apache server response?

If I connect on Docker container, the Apache server is started:

`sudo docker exec -i -t ID /bin/bash`

`curl 127.0.0.1` :

*`<html><body><h1>It works!</h1>`*

Also, on a remote computer (my PC), I have test.com pointed to my server's public IP. If I access example.com, I get the same NGINX response.

And one more question: is this a good approach, to isolate/run a live websites on docker container? Or should I look for another VM solution?

Thanks in advance.

Edited: the problem was inside my NGINX config file. The strange thing, I get no error from NGINX server.

Changed from

```
location \ {
```

to

```
location / {
```

It works fine now. Thanks @Oliver Charlesworth.

Comment: "location \" seems wrong to me...

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you alot!